# How to add a protected configuration with access to properties to a Spring Boot Test context?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, unit-testing, spring-test

i use JUnit 5 with Spring Boot 2.5.2 . Now i want to write a Unit test, that does not load the full Application context.
Therefore i annotate my test like that:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ConfigurationA.class})
class Test1{
...
}
```

In ConfigurationA the Bean1 gets created.
The Problem is that the ConfigurationA accesses an ConfigurationB for creating Bean1, but ConfigurationB is protected.

Now i get the following Error:

> Error creating bean with name 'Bean1' defined in com.package.sample.config.ConfigurationA: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through method 'createBean1' parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.package.sample.config.ConfigurationB available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {}

When i change @ContextConfiguration... to @SpringBootTest it works but the whole Context gets loaded.

Is there any solution to load not the whole context?

Answer (score 0):

Just make ConfigurationA extend ConfigurationB